# Does this recurrence relation run in $ \Theta(n) $?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computer-science, recursive-algorithms, recursion

This is the recurrence relation I am trying to solve:
\begin{align}
T(n) & = 2 \cdot T \left( \frac{n}{4} \right) + 16, \\
T(1) & = c.
\end{align}
I broke this down (i.e., solved this recurrence relation) to $ \sqrt{2} * c * n + 32 * \sqrt{2} * n - 32 $, which runs in tight bounds $ \Theta(n) $. Can you guys confirm this? I’ll show more of my work if this answer is incorrect.

Comment: Did you mean $T(1) = c$? Even so, this would only make sense if $n$ is always a power of $4$.

Comment: For a complete solution you should get $$T(n) = 2^{\log_4 n} T(1) + 16 \left(2^{\log_4(n)-1} - 1\right)$$ start with $S(n) = T(4^n)$ and solve the recursion for $S$.

Comment: @PedroVeras Yeah I fix that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually did most of the steps of solving this recurrence relation correctly. If anyone's having as similar issue, here is my mistake

My issue was that I simplified $2^{\frac{log_2n}{2}}$ as $2^{\frac12}*2^{log_2n}$, not $(2^{log_2n})^{\frac12}$. If I used the exponential rule correctly, I would have gotten $\theta(n^{\frac12})$.

Answer (score 1):

Following Wikipedia's notation for the master theorem, you have $a=2,b=4,f(n)=16$. So $\log_b(a)=\log_4(2)=1/2$, so $f(n)=O(n^{\log_b(a)})$. So we are in case 1, and $T(n)=\Theta(n^{1/2})$. So somewhere you made a mistake.